# How to convert an item in a 2D array to a number

Tags: javascript, node.js

I ran into a problem when i try to grab the price in a array

this is the array that im working on

```
[ [ 'bento box b - sashimi', 'box combo', '$9.59' ],
  [ 'bento box a - chicken teriyaki', 'box combo', '$8.59' ] ]
```

I know that '$9.59' this is string and i try

```
for (item of lunch) {
      let newPrice = parseInt(item[2] *1.8)
        console.log(newPrice)


    }
```

when i run this it will return NaN

I know that '$9.59' this is string and i try

```
    for (item of lunch) {
          let newPrice = parseInt(item[2] *1.8)
            console.log(newPrice)


        }
```

when i run this it will return NaN

I need to times the price in each array by 1.8 but it always give me NaN, how can i fix it?

Comment: consider formatting the question so code is in code blocks, and not code is not in code blocks, and don't repeat yourself at the end, it's annoying

Comment: it keeps telling me i need to add some details

Comment: because you made everything CODE - don't indent text unless it is code

Comment: `parseInt('$9.59')` - results in `NaN` ... because of the `$` ... and `parseInt` would drop the `.59` anyway ... you want `parseFloat(item[2].slice(1)) * 1.8` - note the placement of `()` does NOT include the `* 1.8` since that does not require parsing

Comment: also, why the tag spam ... this is neither `asynchronous`, nor have anything to do with `promise`

Comment: What does this have to do with promises and asynchronous code?

Comment: `I ran into a problem ..` your problem is a lack of critical thinking.  What exactly is an integer? Does it have decimal places?

Answer (score -1):

There are three problems here (aside from the poor formatting):

1. You are performing the multiplication *inside* of the `parseInt()` call. This means the interpreter will first perform `item[2] * 1.8` (the result of which is NaN because the string cannot be converted to a number) and then pass that NaN result to `parseInt()`, which again gives NaN.
2. The strings you are trying to use `parseInt()` on contain a dollar sign $, so the parsing will fail anyway. You need to strip off the dollar sign before parsing using some function such as String.slice() or String.replace().
3. The strings you are trying to parse are not integers. Integers are whole numbers and do not have a decimal place. Try `parseFloat()` instead.